# Derive wallet ID from receive address

Tags: wallet, address

Although there is a related [question](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/how-to-get-wallet-id-from-and-address) about how this isn't possible with `cardano-wallet`, there is value in being able to get the wallet id from a receive address even if it requires another tool.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done. The wallet ID is the hash of the public account key. If you have the public account key, you can derive the addresses belonging to it, but it doesn't work the other direction.